# Redis Insight. Are you behind a proxy? If so, please set the RedisInsight environment variables

Tags: kubernetes, redis, kong-ingress, redisinsights

I deployed RedisInsight in a Kubernetes Cluster, and expose it using a Kong Ingress. When I access it in the web I never pass the privacy settings, it tell me "Something went wrong submitting your preference. Are you behind a proxy? If so, please set the RedisInsight environment variables."

I tried this solution: https://github.com/RedisInsight/RedisInsight/issues/879#issuecomment-1191790107 that leads me to configure RITRUSTEDORIGINS according to: https://docs.redis.com/latest/ri/using-redisinsight/proxy/#trusted-origins, but I get the same error.

Update: It was a misspelling, setting the RITRUSTEDORIGINS environment variable it works.

Answer (score 0):

Just set this Environment variable to true like this:

```
-e RIPROXYENABLE=true
```